# Коммандная строка WINDOWS

Tags: windows, cmd

### OS Windows 10 PRO.

Есть возможности записать команду в переменную коммандной строки ?
Нужно так:

переменная=комманда для получения имени пользователя

Answer (score 0):

Ну например:

### [test.bat]

```
set mycommand=@echo off ^&& cls ^&& cmd /c dir ^&& pause ^&& exit
%mycommand%
```

А уж команду на получение имени пользователя - это уж как-нибудь Вы сами... тем более что мало ли о каком пользователе речь...

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Comment: Мало знаешь мало можешь. (мне долго изучать). Оказывается есть предопределенная переменная &UserName%.

Comment: @Tiny *Оказывается есть предопределенная переменная &UserName%.* Только учтите - она сравнительно элементарно переопределяется...

Comment: В каком смысле как это понять ? Вы имеете ввиду есть разлчия в v.Windows для определения этой переменной ?

Comment: Я имею в виду, что пользователь может изменить значение переменной, и результат работы скрипта станет неверным.

Comment: Аа, Окей я понял.